# Can one port receive several different tcp connections?

Tags: sockets

1. How does the server handle multiple request, does it open different ports or just use one port like 8080 or else?
2. Like google, **www.google.com**; when I access google.com, which port google will be open for my tcp connection?

   When we type "www.google.com" as the url, the DNS server only tell us the IP address without the port number.
   when I access my own tomcat server, I type like this: **http:/ /localhost:8080/...**;

   See, there is a port number in there! That makes me confused.

Comment: port 80 is the default port if none is specified, for HTTP anyway.

Comment: Search "ephemeral port".

Answer (score 0):

> How does the server handle multiple request, does it open different ports or just use one port like 8080

It uses one port.

> Like google, www.google.com; when I access google.com, which port google will be open for my tcp connection?

Port 80, or 443 for HTTPS.